# ftp_get() file with partial filename(not a wildcard)

Tags: php, ftp

I need to get a file based on the second half of the filename with PHP

The structure of the filename will always be NAME_123456789.dat where the number is a `tracking_id(unique)`.

The name being `John, Mel, Bronson, etc`. And the number being a `tracking_id`.

What the process will be just for comprehension is that a person will enter their tracking_id. it will extract that from the search bar and plant it in the ftp search in the specific directory. Because the `tracking_id` is unique it should only return one result, hence `ftp_get()` right?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried getting the list of files in the directory first via [`ftp_nlist()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ftp-nlist.php)? From that, you should be able to search for the file you want

Comment: How many files do you expect to be operating in the directory at any given time? If it is a small number, listing the contents via ftp may work suitably. If it is many thousands of files, you might want to store some sort of text manifest file to read from, or index them in a database.

Comment: I don't have an exact number but definitely over 100 at any time. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: the ftp server goes live tomorrow so I can't experiment with it at the moment and am just trying to prepare. @phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the *relatively* small directory size (100+ from comments above), you should be ok first using [`ftp_nlist()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ftp-nlist.php) to list all the files and then searching for and downloading the file you want.

```
$search = '_' . $trackingId . '.dat';
$searchLen = strlen($search);
$dir = '.'; // example directory
$files = ftp_nlist($connection, $dir); 
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // check if $file ends with $search
    if (strrpos($file, $search) === strlen($file) - $searchLen) {
        // found it, download it
        ftp_get($connection, 'some/local/file/path', $dir . '/' . $file);
    }
}
```

---

Better and more future-proof options can be found in [Michael Berkowski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922979/ftp-get-file-with-partial-filenamenot-a-wildcard/51923092#comment90795582_51922979)...

> How many files do you expect to be operating in the directory at any given time? If it is a small number, listing the contents via ftp may work suitably. If it is many thousands of files, you might want to **store some sort of text manifest file** to read from, or index them in a **database**.

These do hinge on how and when the files are uploaded to the FTP server though so given we don't know anything about that, I cannot provide any solutions.

Comment: I will use this tomorrow and let you know how it goes. It looks like it will work though as the idea is not overly complex. Thank you Phil, appreciated!